# duration of a video on Android

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, android-video-player

in this code I try to get the duration of a video with the method `getDuration()` but it doesn't work and it return always -1. What is wrong? Could I get the duration in another way?(The video is an mp4 file putted in the directory raw)

```
    videoPlayer = (VideoView) this.findViewById(R.id.videoView2);
    videoPlayer.setVideoPath("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.video3);
    int duration = videoPlayer.getDuration();
```

Comment: Have you ensured **the video is present at the link?**

Comment: yes, it is because i can see the video

Comment: try to start it and then use function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from getDuration in videoView:

```
public int getDuration(){
    if (isInPlaybackState()) {
        return mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
    }
    return -1;
}
```

So from what I see, you cannot get the correct duration if the video isn't playing. So a possible solution is to start the playback, get the duration to then stop it and restart the video.

Answer (score 0):

Call getDuration inside setOnPreparedListener

```
 videoPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    long duration = videoPlayer.getDuration();
                }
            });
```